# Pyparsing generate binary AST tree with group

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

Hi I am developing a parser for process calculus. I have already developed one which uses `setParseAction` and custom AST classes but now I want to rewrite it to use dicts and list.

```
from pyparsing import *                                                                                                                                                               

integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))                                                                                                                               
variable = Word(alphas,exact=1)                                                                                                                                                       
operand = Word(alphas.upper(), alphanums+"_")                                                                                                                                         
semicol = Literal(";").suppress()                                                                                                                                                     
equals = Literal("=")  

expr = operatorPrecedence( operand,                                                                                                                                                   
[(".", 2, opAssoc.LEFT),                                                                                                                                                          
 ("+", 2, opAssoc.LEFT),]                                                                                                                                                         
)

rmdef = operand + equals + expr                                                                                                                                                       
expr_def = rmdef + semicol                                                                                                                                                                          

test = ["P = A.(B.C + E.D);",                                                                                                                                                         
"P = A.B.C;"                                                                                                                                                                  
]
```

This returns:

```
['P', '=', ['A', '.', [['B', '.', 'C'], '+', ['E', '.', 'D']]]]
['P', '=', ['A', '.', 'B', '.', 'C']]
```

My question is concerning the second example. I would like it to be, how can I do th

```
['P', '=', ['A', '.' [ 'B', '.', 'C' ]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `expr` you have defined the '.' operator to be left-associative, but in your desired output, it is right-associative.  Change:

```
expr = operatorPrecedence(operand,
    [(".", 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
     ("+", 2, opAssoc.LEFT),]
    )
```

to

```
expr = operatorPrecedence(operand,
    [(".", 2, opAssoc.RIGHT),
     ("+", 2, opAssoc.LEFT),]
    )
```

Now this code:

```
for t in test:
    print expr_def.parseString(t).asList()
```

prints

```
['P', '=', ['A', '.', [['B', '.', 'C'], '+', ['E', '.', 'D']]]]
['P', '=', ['A', '.', ['B', '.', 'C']]]
```

Comment: is there a possibility to add non-associative option to pyparsing ? In most of the abstract algebras such a thing can occur.